# Увеличение потребления памяти PyPy со временем

Tags: python, память, сборщик-мусора, pypy

Есть бот для ВК. Код достаточно велик, так что даже упрощенную часть показать не смогу. Проблема в том, что со временем при запуске на PyPy он начинает кушать большие объемы памяти: сначала 100мб, затем через 10-15 минут - 150мб. После этого скорость возрастания сбавляется, но не пропадает: спустя пару дней можно увидеть и 300мб. Бота, если что, запускаю через службы Linux (systemctl) и там же проверяю память (systemctl status ...).

Увеличение потребляемой памяти в самом начале, как я понял, для PyPy норма, но вот постоянное увеличение со временем - уже нет. Единственное, что у меня может кушать память, это словарик, хранящий в себе некоторые кешированные данные, которые возвращаются через copy.copy(). Тем не менее, этот самый словарик очищается каждые n-минут (dict.clear()), да и плюсом порой прогоняется ручной сборщик мусора (gc.collect()).

Что еще можно попробовать предпринять?

Comment: Если прога живёт долгие дни, то как вариант можно настроить перезапуск – традиционный костыль для утечек памяти `:)`

Comment: @AivanF. отличный вариант, спасибо. возьму на заметку)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если программа живёт долгие дни, то можно настроить перезапуск – это традиционный костыль для утечек памяти.

Можно дополнить конфиг файл `systemd` для перезапуска каждые сутки таким образом:

```bsh
[Service]
Type=notify
WatchdogSec=86400
Restart=always
```